# How to reinstate previously saved option?

Tags: plugins, options

I am working on a simple plugin (kind of maintenance plugin) where I am updating the homepage based on user page option choice.

```
function set_hp(){

$page = get_option('get_the_page');

if ( $page )
{
    update_option( 'page_on_front', $page );    
    update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
}
}
add_action('wp', 'set_hp');
```

Now the homepage is updated with user selected one. Is there any way, when the plugin is deactivated, **the previously saved homepage** (* as set in reading.php front page*) is updated.

PS: I tried with

```
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_deactivate' );

function myplugin_deactivate(){
    delete_option( 'page_on_front', $page );
    delete_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
}
```

But this deletes the homepage option and user needs to set this again.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only way WordPress is going to know what the *previous* option was, is if you save it before you change it - since you're replacing the built-in option, it has no way of knowing how to get back to that.

So, you could add a custom 'backup' option that you restore on deactivation.

Something like this when your option is first set:

```
function set_hp(){

   update_option( 'wpse_231804_backup_page_on_front', get_option( 'page_on_front' ) );
   update_option( 'wpse_231804_backup_show_on_front', get_option( 'show_on_front' ) );

   // ... include the rest of your code here ...

}
```

With a simple reverse on deactivation:

```
function myplugin_deactivate(){

   update_option( 'page_on_front', get_option( 'wpse_231804_backup_page_on_front' ) );
   update_option( 'show_on_front', get_option( 'wpse_231804_backup_show_on_front' ) );

}
```